# What is the purpose of main() in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Quick question, when I run a function inside a file called script.js in NodeJS a function called main() is first added onto the callstack.

My question is, is the main() function the entry point to chromes V8 engine where it takes the Javascript source code from script.js and compiles it into much faster machine code?

Any clarification would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right. main() is the first function added into the call stack.

Whenever a new file in NodeJS is been executed it makes its entry point at the main() function which defined in **libuv** library. 
It is not a JavaScript code anyway.
**Libuv** is a multi-platform C library that provides support for asynchronous I/O based on event loops. It is primarily designed for use in Node.js.

You can anyway go through http://libuv.org/ this link to have a strong view in this.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great I'll dig into this!! Thanks!